# Subscribe once using first() or take(1) from Angular EventEmitter

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I have this:

```
import {EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
...
public dialogEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

I tried this in a component:

```
this.x.dialogEmitter.first().subscribe(cb);
```

But it says that subscribe is not a function. Same problem occurs when I try:

```
this.x.dialogEmitter.take(1).subscribe(cb);
```

is there another pattern I can use to only listen for the first event?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here?  You shouldn't be manually subscribing to an `EventEmitter`.

Comment: how else do you subscribe to an event emitter if it's not manual? Sorry I am not following.

Comment: @AlexanderMills do you want to emit the last value from observable to parent component?

Comment: @AlexanderMills You use them in output bindings.  If that's not what you're doing, most likely you want a different kind of observable.

Comment: ah see what you mean - yeah probably want to use a Subject instead of an EventEmitter

Comment: My first thought would be to use a subject, however the EventEmitter should work. EventEmitter is an angular class that extends Subject. There must be something wrong with what `this.x` refers to. Does `this.x` point to your service where dialogEmitter exists?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use extension operators.
In order to use these you need to import them in your code.
For example:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
```

Once you do, the code you presented should work as expected.

You can click the following link to read more about [Understanding Operator Imports](https://www.learnrxjs.io/concepts/operator-imports.html).